# Using action filters to perform transactions

Tags: yii

I want to make a TransactionFilter in Yii to be applied over an action to wrap it in a transaction so I don´t have to write the same code over and over every time I want to use transactions, at least that's the idea. I have

```
class TransactionFilter extends CFilter
{
    public function filter($filterChain)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsPostRequest())
        {
            $transaction= Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
            try {
                $filterChain->run();
                $transaction->commit();
            }catch(Exception $e) {
                $transaction->rollback();
            }
        }
        else
            $filterChain->run();
        }
}
```

This is my filters method in my User class:

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'accessControl',
        'postOnly + delete',
        array('application.components.TransactionFilter + create'),
    );
}
```

I'm assuming $filterChain->run() will eventually execute the action but the problem arises when there's a redirect in the action, it never made it after the $filterChain->run() sentence in the filter

I don't know if this approach would be advisable and posible in Yii, if not I would appreciate the help if there is another approach or I have to stick with the traditional one.

Thank you.

Comment: This is somewhat unsafe in my opinion. When you have redirect should transaction commit, or rollback? You could ovveride `redirect` method and commit if transacion is running, probably not the best solution... There are also more methods like `redirect` which works similar way, like `refresh`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to begin transaction on:

```
protected function preFilter($filterChain)
```

And commit, rollback on :

```
protected function postFilter($filterChain)
```